# Delete a css property from bootstrap3 to avoid incompatibilities

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, templates

How can I delete a specific css property in Bootstrap3 ?

I work with another template from HTML5up. But I'd like to use Bootstrap too for its carousel. I've got conflicts between them. So, I inspected the code with the Firefox debugger and the Bootstrap code seems to be getting priority on my other CSS code. I tried to write my code in main.css, but it's always the Bootstrap code is retained and not my code. I think I should delete or remove the properties I don't need.

More precisely, I want to change a `font-size` to my `p` in my `body`. I write `font-size:21px`; in a main.css but in bootstrap code is `14px` for default. All my texts are in `14px`. The same with the property line-height who's different in bootstrap code.

What is the best way to avoid incompatibilities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load your custom CSS stylesheet **after** the `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap.css.min` to ensure that your custom overridden properties effectively override Bootstrap's.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://path/to/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://path/to/main.css">
```

Removing/adding properties to bootstrap.css will make it difficult to maintain/update as new version come out.

Comment: Optionally, if it is a CSS selector precedence issue you can use the !important on your declarations in main.css ie: `font-size: 21px !important`

Comment: Yes, I all ready have place bootstrap.css in first position. What helped me has been to use the CSS !important attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `font-size: 21px !important;`

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css) as to why it may not be wise to use `!important`

Comment: don't avise to use `!important`